# gee ranadomPoints fails:Polygon too large to be randomly sampled. Must be smaller than a hemisphere when image is not so huge

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection, geemap, sample, samplepoints

I want to sample random points over an image I access using geemap.
I was trying to do it as following:

```
#access elevation image and clip it with the feature collection
img = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').clip(fc)
```

visualize image:
[image]

```
#sample the image with random points:
fc_sample=ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(img.geometry(), points=3500)
fc_sample.getInfo()

>>>EEException: FeatureCollection.randomPoints: Polygon too large to be randomly sampled. Must be smaller than a hemisphere.
```

I could solve it [based on the answer on this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375908/linear-regression-error-in-gee) as following:

```
fc_sample=ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(fc, points=3500)
fc_sample.getInfo()
```

[image]

This is not the first time that I encounter this behavior of image geometry behaves differently than what I would excepted.
**My question is : why is this happens? what is the explanation of this behavior? how can I get the image extent as a parameter that can be used for the random points, instead of "fc" parameter?**

Comment: I would guess this is a performance optimization. It doesn't actually set the footprint of the image when clipping to a feature collection. The geometry might be very complex and memory intensive to evaluate/work with. If you need the geometry, you can `ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').clip(fc.geometry())`.

Comment: @DanielWiell do you want to post it as answer so you can award the bounty prize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess this is a performance optimization. It doesn't actually set the footprint of the image when clipping to a feature collection. The geometry might be very complex and memory intensive to evaluate/work with. If you need the geometry, you can `ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').clip(fc.geometry())`.